# Recyclerview mvvm, как реализовать общение Adapter с Model

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, mvvm

Нашел в интернете пример реализации Recyclerview с помощью mvvm [*ссылка*](https://www.phunware.com/blog/android-clean-coding-approach/). В примере автор описал не сложный функционал, а мне нужно больше.

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.phunware.example.mvvmrecyclerviewblog.viewmodel.DataViewModel"/>
</data>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/data_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:adapter="@{viewModel.adapter}"
    app:data="@{viewModel.data}"
    tools:context="com.phunware.example.mvvmrecyclerviewblog.view.MainActivity"/>
```

В самом адаптере [ссылка на adapter](https://github.com/phunware/blog-android-clean-coding-approach/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/phunware/example/mvvmrecyclerviewblog/adapter/DataAdapter.java) я переопределил метод `getItemViewType(int position)` и теперь когда список прокручен до конца, я хочу уведомить model [ссылка на model](https://github.com/phunware/blog-android-clean-coding-approach/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/phunware/example/mvvmrecyclerviewblog/viewmodel/DataViewModel.java) что нужно загрузить еще данных.

***Вопрос***. Как мне это сделать ?

**Всё ссылки ведут на репозиторий автора**

Comment: Разве подгрузку данных нельзя сделать с помощью Paging Library

Answer (score -1):

1. В Adapter инициализируем переменную `dataViewModel` которая будет содержать 
   ссылку на Model.

   ```
    public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataViewHolder> {
           //...  
           private DataViewModel dataViewModel;
           //...

           public void setDataViewModel(DataViewModel dataViewModel){
               this.dataViewModel = dataViewModel;
           }
   }
   ```
2. Передаем ссылку в Adapter

   ```
   public class DataViewModel extends BaseObservable {
       private static final String TAG = "DataViewModel";
       private static DataAdapter adapter;
       private static List<DataModel> data;

       public DataViewModel() {
           data = new ArrayList<>();
           adapter = new DataAdapter();

           adapter.setDataViewModel(this); // <- передаем ссылку.
       }  }
   ```